# Testing Controller Concerns (in Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activesupport

I created a in-house gem for managing records called 'record_search', which includes a controller named 'ApiController'  In one app, I needed to hook in authorization behaviors to prevent the data from being publicly accessible, so I added a ActiveSupport::Concern module to allow the app to add a before_filter.  How can I properly test this before_filter? (using rspec)

In Gem:

**app/controllers/api_controller.rb**

```
module RecordSearch
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def search
      render json: #app-specific code
    end

    def find
      render json: #app-specific code
    end

    include Extensions #define any authorization logic here
  end
end
```

Local app:

**app/controllers/concerns/record_search/extensions.rb**

```
module RecordSearch::Extensions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ApplicationHelper #defines current_user method

  included do
    before_filter :require_premium_user, :only => [:find,:search]
  end

  private

  def require_premium_user
    unless current_user
      return render :json => {"error" => "not authorized"}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `controller` is the current controller under test, then you could use:

```
describe "searching when not a premimum user" do
   let(:user) { ... } # code to create a regular user
   before { ... } # code to login user
   it "should return an error message" do
      expect(controller).to receive(:render).with({"error" => "not authorized"})
      # code to trigger find or search
   end
end
```

with comparable examples for a premium user. See also http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_response, although I'm not familiar with using Rails' assertions.

As an aside, the actual `require_premium_user` code didn't make sense to me.